# my redux/saga is looping only on one action

Tags: reactjs, redux, saga

So I am having issues updating to redux and then loading. i can load lists fine but once i update the list and try to get them back with inside the updateCustomerExistingWishList() saga call with getWishlists(customerId) it just loops and loops... i just need a way to update the lists on the UI when an update is made so that the UI shows the new list info

index.tsx file

```
 const lists: any[] = useAppSelector((state) => state.wishLists?.wishLists?.data);

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getWishlist(6));
}, [lists]);
```

using this useEffect to update the change also loops ^^^

reducer:

```
const wishListsState = {
 loading: true,
 wishLists: [],
 wishList: null,
 products: null
};

const reducer = (state = wishListsState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case CREATE_WISHLIST:
   state = {
    ...state,
    loading: true,
    wishLists: null
  };
  break;
  case UPDATE_WISHLIST:
  state = {
    ...state,
    loading: true,
    wishList: null
  };
  break;
  case UPDATE_WISHLIST_SUCCESSFUL:
  state = {
    ...state,
    loading: true,
    wishList: action.payload
  };
  break;
case GET_WISHLIST:
  state = {
    ...state,
    loading: true,
    wishLists: null
  };
  break;
  case GET_WISHLIST_SUCCESSFUL:
   state = {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    wishLists: action.payload
  };
  break;
 default:
  state = { ...state };
    break;
 }
 return state;
 };

export default reducer;
```

actions:

```
export const updateWishlist = (
 updateCustomerList: UpdateCustomerList,
 customerId: number,
 id: number,
 ) => {
return {
  type: UPDATE_WISHLIST,
   updateCustomerList,
   customerId,
   id,
 };
};

export const updateWishlistSuccessful = (wishLists: any
 ) => {
  return {
   type: UPDATE_WISHLIST_SUCCESSFUL,
   payload: wishLists
  };
};

export const getWishlist = (customerId: number) => {
 return {
  type: GET_WISHLIST,
  customerId
 };
};

 export const getWishlistSuccessful = (wishLists: any) => {
  return {
   type: GET_WISHLIST_SUCCESSFUL,
   payload: wishLists
  };
 };
```

SAGA file:

```
getCustomerWishlistsParams = { customerId: number };
function* getCustomerWishlists({ customerId }: getCustomerWishlistsParams) {
 try {
  yield call(customerWishlistsApi, customerId);
 } catch (error: any) {
  yield put(apiError(error?.response?.data?.message));
 }
}

type getCustomerWishlistsParamsSuccessful = { customerId: number };
 function* getCustomerWishlistsSuccessful({ customerId }: 
getCustomerWishlistsParamsSuccessful) {
 try {
 let productDTO: ProductDTO = yield call(customerWishlistsApi, customerId);
 yield put(getWishlistSuccessful(productDTO));
 } catch (error: any) {
 yield put(apiError(error?.response?.data?.message));
 }
}

type updateCustomerExistingWishListSuccessParams = {
updateCustomerList: any;
customerId: number;
id: number;  
callback: any;
};
function* updateCustomerExistingWishList({
 updateCustomerList,
 customerId,
 id,
}: updateCustomerExistingWishListSuccessParams) {
 try {
  yield call(updateWishlistApi, updateCustomerList, customerId, id);
  yield put(updateWishlist(updateCustomerList, customerId, id));
 } catch (error: any) {
 yield put(apiError(error?.response?.data?.message));
 }
}

type updateCustomerExistingWishListParams = {
 updateCustomerList: any;
 callback: any;
 customerId: number;
 id: number;
};
function* updateCustomerExistingWishListSuccesful({
 updateCustomerList,
 customerId,
 id
}: updateCustomerExistingWishListParams) {
try {
  let productDTO: ProductDTO = yield call(updateWishlistApi, updateCustomerList, 
customerId, id);
 yield put(updateWishlistSuccessful(productDTO));
} catch (error: any) {
 yield put(apiError(error?.response?.data?.message));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `useEffect` dependency is causing the loop. `getWishlist` updates `wishlists` which `lists` is referencing.

The `useEffect` will run every time `lists` changes and it will change every time you call `getWishList` (since a new payload is stored in state).

You can likely resolve this by removing `lists` as a dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getWishlist(6));
}, []);
```

However if the `customerId` is dynamic, you could also use that as your `useEffect` dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getWishlist(customerId));
}, [customerId]);
```

This way you will always have `lists` point to the data of the latest wishlist, and you will only dispatch when `customerId` changes.

Comment: it will be dynamic. but i dont have it dynamic yet just calling the 6 for now since thats in the SQL DB.

Comment: Ok well seems like the issue is resolved based on my response, if not please clarify

Comment: No the issue of showing the updated list when the update it made is not resolved it still loops. Checking the lists state in index.tsx loops it or adding the action getwishlist() to the saga update call will loop it.